# Django 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a problem with django, I get name from Html index page and after that ı want to request data. And after ı want to reach that data with gettin html name.

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
import requests
api_key = "35c1fbfe2a35fd3aaf075e7394bf8855"
url = "http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key="+api_key
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/" , methods = ["GET","POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        firstCurrency = request.form.get("firstCurrency") # EURO
        secondCurrency = request.form.get("secondCurrency") # TRY
        amount = request.form.get("amount") #20
        response = requests.get(url)
        #app.logger.info(response)
        infos = response.json
        firstValue = infos["rates"][firstCurrency]
        secondValue = infos["rates"][secondCurrency]
        result = (secondValue / firstValue) * float(amount)
        currencyInfo = dict()
        currencyInfo["firstCurrency"] = firstCurrency
        currencyInfo["secondCurrency"] = secondCurrency
        currencyInfo["amount"] = amount
        currencyInfo["result"] = result
        #app.logger.info(infos)
        return render_template("index.html",info = currencyInfo)
    else:
        return render_template("index.html")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

ı have a problem with `firstValue = infos["rates"][firstCurrency]` this line, why ?

Comment: this is not Django but Flask

Comment: You are right ist my fault.
I was working on django yesterday 
i must have messed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`.json(…)`** [readthedocs]](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) is a *method*, you should *call* the method to read the data as a JSON blob:

```
infos = response.json()  # ←  call the method
```

Comment: It's a seriously simple mistake. I missed it. Thank you so much